# Merge carousel and accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have implemented a content fade in slide show inside the sliding content panel.

Fade in slide show is in the first li of the sliding panel but the problem is since sliding is moving randomly I am not able to show the slide show.

What I need is, Sliding should wait until the slideshow completes its animation. Once slideshow is done then the next li of the sliding panel should come up.

Here is the code used for that

```
//Fade in slide show
var quotes = $(".inner_detail div");
    var quoteIndex = -1;

    function showNextQuote() {
        ++quoteIndex;
        quotes.eq(quoteIndex % quotes.length)
            .fadeIn(2000)
            .delay(2000)
            .fadeOut(2000, showNextQuote);
    }

    showNextQuote();    
//Slider
    $('#news-container').vTicker({ 
        speed: 800,
        pause: 3000,
        animation: 'fade',
        mousePause: false,
        showItems: 1
    });
```

If you wanna see the slideshow effect, please remove the slider code in js and then you  can see how slideshow works. (Here a **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mvNEE/2/)** to show only slideshow)

Here is the working **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mvNEE/1/)** (in this demo the first sliding li has the slideshow div which cant be seen because sliding is moving fast)

Thanks in advance...

Comment: making `pause: 6000,` will help you; basically it's a sum of your slide show

Comment: But the fade items are not fixed, they may increase

Comment: then it should be (6000 * [No of items in slideshow])

Comment: @MVC3Seeker I meant to say that items are dynamic, you never know how much will be loading so I need a solution to calculate it dynamically and stop for that much secs

Comment: `pause: 6000 * (quotes.length-1)`  [link](http://jsfiddle.net/mvNEE/24/)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31326/discussion-between-sowmya-and-mvc3seeker)

Comment: jsfiddle.net/mvNEE/25 check this fiddle I have included fade div in another li, it is calculating all fade elements

Comment: @MVC3Seeker Need your response